# Parsing JSON and adding objects to array only working on second button press?

Tags: java, android, arrays, json, okhttp

I am having an issue with my Android Studio application in that I am trying to parse JSON data from a URL and create objects "Director" with the data and then store each object in an array. The problem is that when I press the button to start the method that does this, Logcat shows that at the end of the method nothing was added to the array. However, when I press the button a second time they get added to the array. Below is my code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements MainAdapter.OnCompanyClickedListener {

    private Button search;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        //Button to start method
        search = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSearch);
        search.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                searchCompanyDirectors("02293426");
            }
        });
    }

    //Parse JSON File From API and Create Directors
    public void searchCompanyDirectors(final String companyNumber){
        Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable(){
            @Override
            public void run(){
                HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();
                try{
                    final String response = httpClient.run("https://MyApiURL"+companyNumber);
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){
                        @Override
                        public void run(){
                            try {
                                JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
                                JSONArray array = jsonObject.getJSONArray("items");
                                for (int i = 0; i < array.length();i++){
                                    JSONObject o = array.getJSONObject(i);
                                    String appointment = o.getString("links");
                                    String parsedAppointment = parseApp(appointment);

                                    Director director = new Director(o.getString("name"),parsedAppointment);
                                    Director.directorList.add(director);
                                }
                            Log.d("tag1",Director.directorList.toString());
                            }catch (JSONException e){
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }
                    });
                }
                catch (Exception ex){
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
        thread.start();
        Log.d("tag2",Director.directorList.toString());
    }

    //Parse Returned String From JSON
    public String parseApp(String appointment){
        String[] arrayDirectors = appointment.split("/",3);
        String[] split = arrayDirectors[2].split("\\\\");
        return split[0];
    }
}

    @Override
    public void onCompanyClicked(int position){
        //Do stuff with directorlist...
    }
```

My Director Class:

```
public class Director {

    private String name;
    private String appointment;

    public static List<Director> directorList = new ArrayList<>();

    public Director (String name, String appointment){
        this.name = name;
        this.appointment = appointment;
    }

    public String getName() {

        return name;
    }
}
```

Logcat "tag1" output on first button press:

```
[Director1, Director2, Director3]
```

Logcat "tag2" output on the first button press:

```
[]
```

Logcat "tag1" output on the second button press:

```
[Director1, Director2, Director3, Director1, Director2, Director3]
```

Logcat "tag2" output on the second button press:

```
[Director1, Director2, Director3]
```

The problem with this arises when I try to make use of the directorList in the last method (it does stuff based on the directorList array), however because the array is empty when the method is finished on the first button press, it doesn't do what it is supposed to do. I am also unsure as to why Logcat "tag2" is showing the the values being added to the array in the middle of the method and then the array being empty at the end of the method whereas Logcat "tag1" is showing the values being added?

Comment: Because you are working on thread.. and HttpClient is async task. this task requires some time to fetch data from server and processing on them.. So i suggest you to use some advanced libraries like https://square.github.io/retrofit/
and https://developer.android.com/training/volley to do networking task

Comment: `thread.start();` ,i think this is the issue,everytime you call this the previous data which you get is gone and it give empty array because it takes time  to fetch data from server ,again when thread run, the output of previous result and now is combine i.e `[Director1, Director2, Director3, Director1, Director2, Director3]` and then when you print `tag2` you get `[Director1, Director2, Director3]`,

Comment: @Krishna Vyas Thanks for the reply! I am still unsure as to why this isn't working though. If the directorList in a seperate java class is being filled with the fetched data why is it then being emptied when the fetching is finished?

Comment: @Swati thanks for the reply! Why is the previous data gone though if I am filling an array in a seperate java class with it?

Comment: @Krishna Vyas Hey so I implemented volley as oppose to HttpClient and I am still getting the same result

Comment: @Sean this is happening because you trying to access directorlist before fetching response from server, you have to access direcorlist after getting response from server (like in onResponse method, if you are using Volley)

Comment: see some examples like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32731424/return-modified-arraylist-outside-of-volley-onrsponse , https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35558566/volley-how-do-i-return-the-arraylist-from-onresponse-method-in-volley

Comment: @Krishna Vyas Ahh I think I understand now, thank you so much for your responses!